# Java Android button doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-view

I'm new to Java Android programming. I want to integrate a button with a listener, but I can't get it to work.

```
public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

   private EditText text;   

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Log.e("AOWN", "STARTED !");
    }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
       Log.e("AOWN", "I just clicked !");
   }
}
```

I know how to iterate all buttons (R class), but method onClick won't get called!

I tried to add a test Button and attach a listener to it, and it's working but It's much more to code and I'm lazy.

This is working but It's much more to code and I'm following a book where the action is fired up with onClick() method.

```
public class MainClass extends Activity{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Log.e("AOWN", "STARTED !");

      // Like in java with SelectionListener
      Button bTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      bTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){
              Log.e("AOWN", "It's working but it's much more to code and I'm freakn lazy.");
          }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: "...and it's working but It's much more to code and I'm lazy." Are you trolling us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never set an onClickListener in your original code. You just need to do something like this:

```
  Button bTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  bTest.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Comment: @AND_DEV: Pearson's answer is correct. Did *you* read the post?

Comment: yeah he said(in second half) if add button instance it is working that means he already know what perason's answer is , but he wants something like without creating button instance, Like we add onclick in xml file only,

Comment: No, he didn't want to add an anonymous inner class for each button. You still have to assign a listener to each button that should react, even if your Activity implements OnClickListener. Yes, you can add methods in XML, but for the example given, this is his solution.

Comment: I think he was failing to realize you could add a class that implemented `onClickListener`, without actually creating a new class in the `setOnClickListener` method. Hence my answer. If you have a better interpretation of what he said, feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick answers, and I'm sorry if my thread isn't clear as well to understand. I can attach a clickListener to any button on my layout and can handle what I'm clicking but I don't understand what's the role of implementing OnClickListener if the overrided method onClick(View view) doesn't get called? I don't want to create N type of Buttons then attach for every button a listener to handle data. I thought if I only implement OnClickListener and add onClick(View view) method it's will working. Anyway thanks for helping me!

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian: Your Activity implements OnClickListener, so now your Activity essentially *is* an OnClickListener. However, you still have to assign that listener to each button (hence the "this" in setOnClickListener(this)). The Activity is the "this", and you have to tell each button to use the activity as the click listener.